# Как сопоставить тип c# double с типом decimal в sql serveк?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Как сопоставить тип c# double с типом decimal в sql serveк?

Comment: какое отношение имеет "округление" к "форматированию"?

Comment: никакого... я просто получаю 1,12 с запятой, а мне надо с точкой

Comment: где Вы это "получаете"?

Comment: в CommandText передаю запрос вида $"...select (price = {price})"

Comment: [String.Replace( ',' , '.' )](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx), и пр. сначала смотрите на русифицированном MSDN.

Comment: [Отредактируйте ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/785696/edit), уберите все лишнее,, например про округление, и добавьте нужное, что писали в комментариях.

Answer (score 2):

Десятичный разделитель при преобразовании в строку устанавливается исходя из текущей локали(культуры, кому как нравится). В русской локали по дефолту установлена запятая в качестве разделителя, можете заглянуть в настройки региональных стандартов в панели управления. В вашем случае можно использовать культуро-независимую локаль InvariantCulture:

```
var price = 1.2;
var priceStr = price.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Для интерполированных строк, можно использовать [FormattableString.Invariant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring.invariant?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.FormattableString.Invariant);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.1):

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = FormattableString.Invariant($"...select (price = {price})");
```

P.S.
В случае запросов к БД обычно принято использовать [параметры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx), а не запихивать все в строку:

```
  sqlCommand.CommandText = "... select (price = @price)";
  sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("price", price);
```

В этом случае не нужно будет заботится о форматировании и преобразовании;)